# How to pick a method based on a value of a parameter without use of a switch statement

Tags: java

I have a classes that do validations:
One class does string validation and one does numeric validation and a controller class that picks based on value:

```
public class SomeControllerClass {


    public SomeControllerClass() {
        String test = "Numeric";

        switch (test) {
            case "Numeric":
                System.out.println("CALL THE NUMERIC VALIDATION CLASS");
                break;
            case "String":
                System.out.println("CALL THE String VALIDATION CLASS");
                break;
        }

    }


}


public class StringValidation {
//methods = String validation (Max length etc)
}


public class NumericValidation {
//methods = Is numeric, range etc 
}
```

My question:
Is their a better way to do this withot the use of swich statement?

Comment: How does your cat understand whether a line with a number or a string has arrived?

Comment: Yes you can try using Factory Pattern 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: @Hamza and how would that be without a conditional statement?

Comment: @Hamza This will not work, because classes are not coming in! These are strings!

Comment: You can build a map<string,consumer<string>> and do myMap.get(mytype).accept(mystribgtotest)

Comment: OP could follow the factory pattern example, but replace the if-else construct with a `Map<String, Validation>`.

Comment: @WBLord It will work. In fact the example linked by Hamza uses a string to decide which object is built.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper yes, by using a conditional statement, which the OP doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @Stultuske That was not what OP was complaining about in their comment directed at Hamza though. I'm only addressing that. Others have already addressed alternatives to the use of conditional statements, so I didn't think it was necessary to repeat the same.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper either we see different comments, or the OP hasn't' commented at all.

Comment: @Stultuske No, that was a brainfart on my part, the comment is by WBLord, not by OP. And it's still incorrect, so my comment is valid. Not sure why we are arguing this, anyway.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper have you also checked the other comments, talking about Maps? The OP doesn't want a conditional statement (only specified switch, but if you don't want that, it's clear you don't want if's either, since they're the same, just different syntax). A different approach has been proposed, yet you keep defending the conditional statement option.

Comment: @Stultuske: Have you read my comments? I have addressed that point already.

Comment: I have. if you understand that "repeating what has been said" is somewhat pointless, how is "repeating what has been said and has been pointed out to not meet the requirements" different?

Comment: I am not doing that, though. I believe I have sufficiently explained myself even though I have no obligation to do so, and this is not productive at all. Feel free to have the last word.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I have decided to take the approach @Hamza suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way is to use a Factory pattern. You will need to create a factory that can provide you an appropriate validator based on your value. That's the answer in the nutshell.

I dealt with similar problem in Spring boot app context. The problem was that if I need to use in some bean an implementation of the interface but I only know which one I need at runtime based on some key (like in your situation). I wrote my own solution with what I called self-populating factory. Basically by the time application runs I have a factory that could give me any implementation of a particular interface. Here is [Javadoc page](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/package-summary.html) that explains it. Also you can read this article: [Non-intrusive access to "Orphaned" Beans in Spring framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-intrusive-access-orphaned-beans-spring-framework-michael-gantman/). It explains the feature and tells you where to get the MgntUtils Open-Source library that includes the feature. A disclaimer: the MgntUtils library is written and maintained by me

Comment: it's always better to put the examples of your answer (if only in a minimalistic form) in the answer itself. It'll preserve the answer if the page itself is moved/deleted

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's better to use `Factory Pattern`. However, I am giving a suggestion that does not use any factory pattern or switch statements.

It may not be an ideal coding example.

---

I have assumed certain things here since I am not sure what is `String test = "Numeric"` means.

- If it is mean you will get `Numeric` and `String` as actual values and not as a possible datatype of value(actual value can be "30.00" or "Some String Value") then the below suggestion will not work. Don't need to read the rest.
- If that is not the case then there is another problem, by `Numeric` it can mean int, long or double. I am giving example considering `Double`.You can change yours accrodingly.

Idea is to try to parse the numeric data into the desired data and if it parses successfully then call `NumericValidation` otherwise call the `StringValidation`

```
String test = "30.00"; //your input

boolean valid = false;
try{
    Double dVal = Double.parseDouble(test);
    //call your method however you want its just an example. 
    //Once we don't have any exception we can perform validation here.
    valid =new NumericValidation().validation(dVal); 
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //since we got exception its not a numeric value and we can proceed with StringValidation.
    valid = new StringValidation().validation(test);
}
```

Demo Validation Classes

```
public class StringValidation {
    public boolean validation(String val) {
        //logic
    }
}

public class NumericValidation {

    public boolean validation(Double val) {
       //logic 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeControllerClass {


public SomeControllerClass() {
    String test = "10";
    boolean numeric=true;;
    try {
         Double num= Double.parseDouble(test);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         numeric =false;
    }
    finally{
        if(numeric) {
            NumericValidation.getIntance();
        }
        else {
            StringValidation.getIntance();
        }
        
    }
    

   }


}

public class NumericValidation {


  private static NumericValidation instance = null;
    private NumericValidation() {
        System.out.println("NumericValidation");
    }
    public static NumericValidation getIntance() {
        if(instance==null) {
            instance=new NumericValidation();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.print("fsdffffff");
    }
 }

public class StringValidation {
private static StringValidation instance = null;
private StringValidation() {
    System.out.println("Stringvalidation");
}
public static StringValidation getIntance() {
    if(instance==null) {
        instance=new StringValidation();
    }
    return instance;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

public class SomeControllerClass {

```
public SomeControllerClass() {
    String test = "Numeric";

    switch (test) {
        case "Numeric":
            System.out.println("CALL THE NUMERIC VALIDATION CLASS");
            NumericValidation obj=NumericValidation.getIntance();
            break;
        case "String":
            System.out.println("CALL THE String VALIDATION CLASS");
            StringValidation obj1 = StringValidation.getIntance();
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: ok. And how exactly is this NOT using a switch?